# Invertion of an equation involving an integral

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve the following equation numerically for $\mu$, but I'd like to keep $T$ and $n_e$ as parameters for easier plots. $$ n_e = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^\infty dp\, p^2\frac{\sinh \left(\frac{\mu }{T}\right)}{\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{{m_e}^2+p^2}}{T}\right)+\cosh \left(\frac{\mu}{T}\right)} $$

I tried the following code

```
me = 0.51 10^-3;
Ke = 8.62 10^-14;
ne[\[Micro]_, T_] := ne[\[Micro], T] = 1/\[Pi]^2 NIntegrate[p^2*Sinh[\[Micro]/T]/(Cosh[Sqrt[me^2 + p^2]/T] + Cosh[\[Micro]/T]), {p, 0, \[Infinity]}]
FindRoot[10 == ne[\[Micro], 10^2*Ke], {\[Micro], 0.10}]
```

But got an error saying that the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region of integration...

Comment: Get rid of this `ne[\[Micro]_, T_] := ne[\[Micro], T] = ...` and just use `ne[\[Mu]_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] :=`  and change `\[Micro]` to `\[Mu]` (_this last part has no functional effect but it's bad style to use an SI prefix symbol instead of a Greek letter_). Then ```Remove["Global`*"]``` and re-evaluate. You'll still get warnings about poor convergence.

Comment: I tried out some different integration methods but they still had warnings, and LocalAdaptive had no warnings but was incorrect. The best I could get was $\mu = 6.7$ but I have no idea if that's accurate.

Comment: Thanks but it keeps telling me that it encountered a singular Jacobian, whatever value I use as starting point (Btw, ne is ~10^30 and T ~ 10^-3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m = 0.51 10^-3;
ParametricPlot3D[{T, 
  Log[Sinh[μ/T]*π^-2 NIntegrate[
     p^2/(Cosh[Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]/T] + Cosh[μ/T]), {p, 0, 
      100}]], μ}, {T, 1, 5}, {μ, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["T", Italic, 16], 
   Style["log(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(e\)]\))", Italic, 16], 
   Style["μ", Italic, 16]}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

If you want to make a solution in a form of a list, replace  `ParametricPlot3D` by `Table`.

Have fun!